# Is there any way to give Boxcars 15 Med-X?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

Boxcars says that, since I'm the Powder Gangers' "Grim [expletive] Reaper," if I give him 15 Med-X, he'll OD and die for me.

But my only options (while carrying 43 Med-X's) are 1, 2, 3 and 5. If I give him 5, I don't seem to have an option to give him more.

Is there any way to get him to OD? Or if I'm playing pro-NCR (who would kill him anyway), is my only in-character option to shoot him?

Comment: Maybe he was being sarcastic? Giving him Med-X awards good karma, so I don't think there's a way to kill him by overdose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot OD him to death, the only answer is shooting.

However *MINOR SPOILER*:

> You'll need him for another quest, later on.